# Pass a class as a parameter and make property of the class being generated dynamically c#

Tags: c#

Currently, I have the following 2 classes:

```
public class FirstClass
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

public class SecondClass
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

And I bind those class properties from the database like the following, and I thought that I will make a generic method to call database, as only the property is different from each other:

```
public IEnumerable<T> PopulateData() where T : class, new()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var generic = new T()
                    {
                        // This will be filled with Username, Fullname, Email for FirstClass and add the Age for SecondClass and I confused about this part
                    };
                    yield return generic;
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I would call it like this:

```
PopulateData<FirstClass>();
PopulateData<SecondClass>();
```

But I couldn't think about how it works. Any idea and help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Look at Entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your columns in the DataReader match the members of your class or you have some kind of mapping, I guess you can use reflection to populate them dynamically.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h(v=vs.110).aspx

So you would use `.SetValue` to set the value in the `generic` object you declared, but you would have to use reflection to get a `FieldInfo` object.

There will be some overhead in all this, and I'm sure a lot of frameworks like this already exist, so before you go further down this road, you might want to fully evaluate your design in light of progress made in ORMs and related techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this extension method with datatables for a long time now. You may change it to use IDataReader as well. The extension method will convert every datatable to a concrete class list of objects as long as the class properties and column names in datatable are the same. Here is the extension method

```
public static List<T> ToGenricList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();

            foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
            {
                T obj = new T();

                foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                list.Add(obj);
            }

            return list;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Disclaimer:** I got this method from another stackoverflow fellow but I am unable to find the question link now